# javascript: register a second event listener. How to prevent certain events go to it

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have a bit of code where I register a keydown listener to my input type text.

The usual

```
  if (...) {
 mytext. addEventListener('keydown', myhandler ,true); 
} else {
mytext.attachEvent('onkeydown', myhandler ); // older versions of IE
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

My problem begins when somebody using my API register an event listener keydown as well.

How can I ensure that certain events are not passed to his/her code unless I want so ?

In short, that would imply that event-notification would reach me first  which I believe is not guaranteed to be the case ?

Note: this is nothing to do with event-propagation on parent events (bubbling up). I am just dealing with another listener on the same HTML element

Any suggestions, ideas ?

I thought of overriding the methods attachEvent and addEventListener but I am not sure if it's a sound idea or not.

Thanks

Comment: Surely someone could only harm themselves by doing this? Why go to particular effort when you can just urge people to use your code properly, and suffer the consequences if they don't?

Comment: @lonesomeday interesting point. Thanks. In fact, I am torn whether it's worth to put this effort. However I thought it was if it's easy to do... which is what I ain't figured yet... hence this query here

Comment: I absolutely cannot recommend overwriting the event methods! It's a bad idea if you prohibit the API user from using normal JS functions... I would'nt use your Code if so.

Comment: How about `document.addEventListener('keydown', func, true)`

Comment: @closure what do you mean ? I am asking how to ensure that a person is not notified of a property why do I have to register it on document then

Comment: @Zo72, sorry for not explaining. If you listen to the event at the document level during `capture` phase and `stopPropagation`, the event will never reach the element. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gDNVM/. AFAIK, does not work for old ie versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also wouldn't recommend to override the `addEventListener` method. But I also think that it can't be bad to try certain things out for oneself to test and see if and where there are certain problems. So anyway, here is an idea of how you could do it:

```
var f = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, func, x){
    var that = this;
    if (that.evts === undefined) {
        that.evts = {};
    }
    if (that.evts[type] === undefined) {
        that.evts[type] = [];
        f.call(that, type, function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < that.evts[type].length; i++) {
                that.evts[type][i].apply(that, arguments);
            }
        }, x);
    }
    that.evts[type].push(func);
};
```

I'm not a hundred percent confident that I didn't miss something but in theory this should override the method in a way, that the order in which eventlisteners are added should be the same as the order in which the handlers are executed.

This is done by saving the handler functions in an array, every time the `addEventListener` method is called, and only add one single eventlistener that traverses that array and executes every function in it.

Of course you would also have to change the `removeEventListener` method to remove the items in your array. And you would have to do the same for `Document.prototype.addEventListener` and `Window.prototype.addEventListener`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V5Aer/1/)**

Note that I added a property called `evts` (which contains the function arrays) to the element to which the listener was added. This is probably not the best way to do it, since anyone can override that property. It probably would be better to store your arrays somewhere in a local variable or at least rename it to something that is unlikely to be overridden by accident.

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort. I am trying this oue... Again it seems a bit scary to put all of this effort to preserve the order...

Comment: @Zo72 yeah, it probably is a little bit scary! And it can't handle things like `button.onclick = function(){...}`. So really, I wouldn't advice this...but it's nice to see what's theoretical possible. I don't know what you are writing but if it's possible, then your first approach probably should be to make your code more robust, so that the order of your eventhandlers and the user's eventhandlers just doesn't matter.